# Duvida com While

Tags: java, while

Sou iniciante e estou com dúvida nos comandos `While` / `Do…While`, segue a dúvida em que questão.

Tenho um exercício  a seguir que a professora resolveu com o comando `Do…While`, fui tentar fazer com o `while` para exercitar e me deparei totalmente sem saída.

> Crie Um programa para validar as seguintes informações.
>
> ```
> nome > 3 caracteres
> idade > 0 e idade < 150
> salario > 0
> sexo ' f ' ou ' m '
> estado civil 's' 'c' 'v' 'd'
> ```

```
    public class Exercicios3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean validaCampo = true;

        System.out.println("Nome: ");
        String nome = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Idade: ");
        int idade = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Salário: ");
        double salario = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Sexo: ");
        char sexo = sc.next().charAt(0);

        System.out.println("Estado Civil: ");
        char estadoCivil = sc.next().charAt(0);

        while (!validaCampo) {
            if (nome.length() < 3) {
                validaCampo = false;
                System.out.println("Nome muito pequeno, digite novamente ");
                nome = sc.nextLine();
            } else if (idade <= 0 && idade > 150) {
                validaCampo = false;
                System.out.println("Idade maior que 0 e menor que 105, digite novamente ");
                idade = sc.nextInt();
            } else if (salario < 0) {
                validaCampo = false;
                System.out.println("Salario tem que ser maior que 0, digite novamente ");
                salario = sc.nextDouble();
            } else if (sexo != 'M' || sexo != 'F') {
                validaCampo = false;
                System.out.println("Caracteres têm que ser M - Masculino e F - Feminino, digite novamente ");
                sexo = sc.next().charAt(0);
            } else if ((estadoCivil != 's') || (estadoCivil != 'c') || (estadoCivil != 'v') || (estadoCivil != 'd')) {
                validaCampo = false;
                System.out.println("Caracteres têm que ser s , c , v ou d, digite novamente");
                estadoCivil = sc.next().charAt(0);
            }

            System.out.println("\nFlag ValidaCampo:" + validaCampo);
            System.out.println("\nNome:" + nome);
            System.out.println("Idade:" + idade);
            System.out.println("Salário:" + salario);
            System.out.println("Gênero:" + sexo);
            System.out.println("Estado Civil:" + estadoCivil);

            sc.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual era a saída esperada e qual saida vc obteve?

Answer (score 2):

Para explicar o que aconteceu vou omitir algumas partes do código, vamos nos concentrar apenas nessa parte:

```
public class Exercicios3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean validaCampo = true;

        [...]

        while (!validaCampo) {
            if (nome.length() < 3) {
                validaCampo = false;
                System.out.println("Nome muito pequeno, digite novamente ");
                nome = sc.nextLine();
            } [...]
        }
    }
}
```

Veja que no início do programa a variável `validaCampo` inicia com `true`:

```
boolean validaCampo = true;
```

Após isso é feita a condição no `while`:

```
while (!validaCampo){...}
```

isso pode ser lido como "Enquanto `validaCampo` for falso faça ...", porém o valida campo é true, sendo assim vai passar direto pelo `while`.

Esse problema não ocorre com o `do ... while` pois a verificação é feita após cada loop, ou seja, o código vai executar pelo menos 1 vez. E após cada verificação o `validaCampo` é alterado para falso caso o campo não satisfaça as condições:

```
if (nome.length() < 3) {
    validaCampo = false;
    [...]
}
```

Um outro problema nesse código é que o `validaCampo` só é alterado para falso dentro do loop, mas nunca para verdadeiro, quando é a hora de sair do `while`?

Outro problema na lógica que percebi é a última linha do while: `sc.close();` Se o `Scanner` é encerrado, o `validaCampo` for falso e o loop recomeçar como você vai ler os próximos valores digitados pelo usuário?

Acredito que sabendo disso você já consegue alterar o seu código para que funcione do jeito que espera.